# Is there an R function that can detect which cpu core a function is running on?

Tags: r, for-loop, parallel-processing

I am running a parallelized nested for-loop on two cores. So, half the for-loop is on one core and the other half is on the other. I want to record each iteration of the loops based on which cpu core it was run on. Is there a function to determine which cpu core a function is running?

Comment: I doubt it ....

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want to know this?

Comment: @GregorThomas I want to know because I am storing a lot of information for each iteration of the for-loop. It would help organize this information if I could keep track of which core the process was run on.

Comment: The loop itself knows what iteration it is on, so I'm not clear how you'd additionally use the CPU assignment.